# Color dynamic cell address based on another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a cell say E28 containing a end value of "$I$22"

So I need to color the I22 cell - it also needs to revert back to normal when E28's value changes to another address that gets colored.

Conditional formatting doesn't seem to be able to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: Easy......does **E28** contain a value or a formula ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - formula. Its got like 5 nauseatingly long if match functions determining the address. Building it in many places just slows performance too much. So I opted to only use it in once and make this thing work as a visible marker..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional formatting.  The CF formula would be:

```
=$E$28=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())
```

Note that the above will only apply for Absolute Addressing.  If you need to account for mixed or relative addressing modes, then you will need this more complex CF formula:

```
=OR($E$28=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),1),$E$28=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),2),$E$28=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),3),$E$28=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4))
```

And ensure the `Applies to` Range covers the appropriate range.

**EDIT** *Showing screen shots demonstrating how to use this:*

`Conditional Formatting Rules Manager` showing the `Applies to` and format

[image]

`Edit Formatting Rule` dialog showing the actual formula
[image]

Screen shot showing I22 colored based on E28
[image]

Screen shot showing G22 colored

[image]

Comment: It doesn't really take your formula.

Comment: I don't know what that means.  The formula works in Excel 2007.  Do you have an earlier version.

Comment: Works on my system....but the data value must be **absolute**:  *$G$7*.

Comment: Ok finally started

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Yes it does.  That is how she shows it in her OP.  If not, there are arguments for the `ADDRESS` function to change the return type.  I'm going to post some screen shots.

Comment: Now we have a new problem. This time the E28 result doesn't point to the same column. I just colored things in column I. When the result goes elsewhere it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @helena4  I'll post the screen shots so you can hopefully figure out the issue.

Comment: Just let me check gary's thing about it always having to be absolute. This will take a little while.

Comment: @helena4 If you need it other than absolute, you can change the ADDRESS function, or use several with different return types embedded in an OR function

Comment: Its fine i just had to add "$"&  to a few places. We are totally done. You might want to put it in the answer for other people (that it needs to be absolute or it wont work).